# CKEditor with widgettemplatemenu and widgetbootstrap

Tags: plugins, widget, ckeditor

I am trying to get a version of the widgetbootstrap working with the widgettemplatemenu and have run into a snag.  This is coded straight from the example found at http://albatrossdigital.github.io/widgetbootstrap/

The screen displays properly:

[image: Menu shows the gear]

When I click the gear icon, the menu drops down and then immediately disappears.

Here is my config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

// %REMOVE_START%
// The configuration options below are needed when running CKEditor from source files.
config.plugins = 'dialogui,dialog,about,a11yhelp,basicstyles,blockquote,clipboard,panel,floatpanel,menu,contextmenu,resize,button,toolbar,elementspath,enterkey,entities,popup,filebrowser,floatingspace,listblock,richcombo,format,horizontalrule,htmlwriter,wysiwygarea,image,indent,indentlist,fakeobjects,link,list,magicline,maximize,pastetext,pastefromword,removeformat,showborders,sourcearea,specialchar,menubutton,scayt,stylescombo,tab,table,tabletools,undo,wsc,lineutils,widget,bootstrapVisibility,autogrow,bbcode,colordialog,devtools,custimage,div,divarea,find,flash,floating-tools,forms,iframe,liststyle,onchange,pagebreak,placeholder,preview,showblocks,stylesheetparser,tableresize,uicolor';
config.skin = 'moono';
config.extraPlugins = 'widgetbootstrap,widgettemplatemenu';
// %REMOVE_END%


config.height = 400;
config.toolbar = [
    [ 'Source', '-', 'NewPage', 'Preview', '-', 'Templates' ],
    [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ],
    [ 'Bold' ],
    [ 'WidgetTemplateMenu' ]
];
allowedContent: 'p a div span h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 section article iframe object embed strong b i em cite pre blockquote small,' +
        'sub sup code ul ol li dl dt dd table thead tbody th tr td img caption mediawrapper br[href,src,target,width,height,colspan,' +
        'span,alt,name,title,class,id,data-options]{text-align,float,margin}(*);';
```

};

I am pretty sure I have all dependent plugins loaded properly.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Thanks,

JG

Update to issue:

I have noticed some other odd behavior.  I added a Styles combo to the page and it exhibits the same behavior as the gear icon. I click and the styles list drops down then disappears.
It may be a coincidence but it seems very odd.

Perhaps missing or corrupt dependency?  Which, by the way I have checked pretty thoroughly.

Comment: dieslable 'floating-tools' may be work!